# Replace div with left-in slide animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I would like to replace a div's contents with another via a slide animation; the first div slides to the left outside of the box (hidden), whilst the second slides in.

I tried this;

http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1203/

But it does not appear to be doing anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
        var $oldBox = $("#signup .box[data-step=1]");
        var $newBox = $("#signup .box[data-step=2]");

        var outerWidth = $oldBox.outerWidth(true);
        var posSlideOut = (2 > 1 ? -outerWidth : outerWidth);
        var posSlideIn = (2 > 1 ? outerWidth : -outerWidth);

        $.when($oldBox.animate({left: posSlideOut}, "slow"), $newBox.css("left", posSlideIn + "px").animate({"left": 0}, "slow"));
```

Comment: You're not triggering an animation by any means. You're just declaring it.

Comment: Your code seems fine, but, it never works. I mean by that, it never execute. The only problem I can see right now, is that you never trigger the animation of the $oldBox. So, never gonna see the execution.

Comment: The default value for the css property [`position`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) is `static`, so changing the [`left`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp) property will not have any effect unless you change `position` to something like `relative`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my update to get the javascript working

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1210/)

The main changes were that I added the `$(document).on('click')` event to fire the animation and switched `left` to `margin-left` since you are not using relative or fixed positioning

This should get you in the right direction

Update:

Also, I added javascript to remove the `"display: hidden;"` from your second div

Comment: Thanks, just 1 q, how can I get the second box to follow along the first box, it should slide in (right to left), as the other box is sliding out.

Comment: From javascript perspective, you just swap the margin values for the `$newBox` and take the `$newBox` animation out of the `$oldBox` animation callback, so they fire at the same time.

For the css, you will need to leverage the relative/absolute positioning. Here's a working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1227/)

Comment: Oh yeah, and now that it does use `relative/absolute` positioning, you can use `left` and `right` instead of `margin-left` and `margin-right`. That fixes the padding issue present in the last comments example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1231/)

Answer (score 1):

**[GreenSock Animation Platform (GSAP)](http://greensock.com/gsap)**  with `TweenLite` / `TweenMax`. It provides much smoother transitions with far greater customization than jQuery or CSS3 transitions. In order to animate CSS properties with TweenLite / TweenMax, you'll also need their plugin called "CSSPlugin". TweenMax includes this automatically.

**First, load the TweenMax library:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

**Or the lightweight version, TweenLite:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/easing/EasePack.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
```

**Then, call your animation:**

```
 var myObj= document.getElementById("myDiv");

// Syntax: (target, speed, {distance, ease})
 TweenLite.to(myObj, .7, { x: 500, ease: Power3.easeOut});
```

**You can also call it with an ID selector:**

```
 TweenLite.to("#myID", .7, { x: 500, ease: Power3.easeOut});
```

**If you have jQuery loaded, you can use more advanced broad selectors, like all elements containing a specific class:**

```
 // This will parse the selectors using jQuery's engine.
TweenLite.to(".myClass", .7, { x: 500, ease: Power3.easeOut});
```

**For full details, see:
[TweenLite Documentation](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenLite/)**

According to their website:
*"TweenLite is an extremely fast, lightweight, and flexible animation tool that serves as the foundation of the GreenSock Animation Platform (GSAP)."*